# Calling REST API break in android

Tags: android, web-services, api

I'm new Android. I have a problem with calling REST API. Actually, I want to response status code from calling API. But, android app is stop! Please pointing me where the problems. Where can I caught to Log. Here my code!

```
 public void callRestApi(){

    HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
    String url = "http://myurl/api/v1/user/login?email=retailers@admin.com&password=admin123";
    HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);

    try {
        //when I breakpoint, the following line is crush. 
        HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);  //crush in here

        StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
        int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
        if (statusCode == 200) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"200", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }  else if(statusCode == 401) {
            Toast.makeText(LoginActivity.this,"401", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }            
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    httpclient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

}
```

I used android permission on Manifest file.

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

I got this error.

1. ***ERROR/InputDispatcher(2276): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed!***
2. ***ERROR/Launcher(2905): Error
   finding setting, default accessibility to not found:
   accessibility_enabled***

Comment: Can you show error stacktrace?

Comment: ERROR/InputDispatcher(2276): channel ~ Channel is unrecoverably broken and will be disposed! and ERROR/Launcher(2905): Error finding setting, default accessibility to not found: accessibility_enabled

Comment: where do you call callRestApi()?

Comment: That REST API come from Laravel!

Answer (score 0):

I got this answer. I has been used ***SDK min version *** to ***16***. When I change to ***7***. All are pretty work fines. But, I don't know why?

Change from `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16"/>` to

```
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Please pointing me why crush in ***sdk version 16***.